# Get the datagrid column count in WPF

Tags: wpf

I need to get the column count of a DataGrid in WPF. I can get the row count like this:

```
var rowCount = Grid.Items.Count;
```

but I need to get the number of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Grid.Columns.Count` should work if `Grid` is a `DataGrid`.

Comment: Thank you  Sir. That's it.I'll tag as answer after 7 minutes